# Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'flaskapp': /var/www/basic-flask-app/app.wsgi, referer: http://www.mywebsite.com

Tags: apache, flask, header, issue-tracking

Can't able to resolve this issue. I have one file named as basic-flask-app.conf in the sites-enabled. below is the file content.

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)

```
WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/basic-flask-app/app.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/basic-flask-app>
    WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/www/basic-flask-app/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/basic-flask-app/logs/access.log combined
```

Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

I added this after googling. Also after research I added processes=1. Then I restarted the apache server also.

Still not working.